# Creating a foreign language on-screen keyboard for CKEditor

Tags: javascript, plugins, ckeditor, google-language-api, on-screen-keyboard

I am using [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/) as a rich text WYSIWYG Javascript editor.
[image: Rich Text Editor]

I would like to add an on-screen keyboard so that they can easily enter text from non-English alphabets.
[image: Google Hebrew Keyboard]

I was planning on finding a JavaScript on-screen keyboard and adding a custom button with a CKEditor plug-in to trigger it.

I've found a [couple](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/scripting/jvk.aspx) of JavaScript on-screen keyboards. [I like the one that Google provides best.](http://code.google.com/apis/ajaxlanguage/documentation/#Keyboard) The problem is that it needs to be bound to an HTML `<textarea>`. As far as I can tell CKEDitor uses an iFrame and has no `<textarea>`. Does anyone have any ideas for how to work around this problem? Is there a way I can bind the keyboard to the CKEditor "`<textarea>`"? Or is there an on-screen keyboard that doesn't need to be bound to anything?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this one
http://debugger.ru/demo/projects/virtualkeyboard/richedit/ckeditor/plugins/Jsvk/examples/sample.html

There you'll see development release, but shortly it will be replaced with production one.
Project page: http://sf.net/prokects/jsvk/